# Low volume level on MediaPlayer - Android Things

Tags: android-mediaplayer, android-things

I have a rather murky problem with low level of audio output on Android Things.
My HW setup is RPI 3 (Raspberry) running Google IoT RPI3 ver 1.0.2, audio output trough headphone jack.

This is the [simple audio](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m3li7ALsgOpiMA0gvV_rUaaH_86_B0_G) file I downloaded somewhere off the internet. I imported it into raw folder of my project. And tried to run.

Here is my simple code so you can reproduce:

```
package com.mystuff.lowvolumeissue;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sampleaudio);
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1);
        mediaPlayer.start(); // no need to call prepare(); create() does that for you
    }
}
```

just to make sure everything is set up correctly this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mystuff.lowvolumeissue">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<application>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.IOT_LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

When hearing the output trough headphones the level of sound is barely 50% of what is the output when I play the same sample on a PC trough headphones.

Someone has come up with similar issue [here](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant/issues/54).

Any suggestion how solve this?

Comment: I've run into similar weirdness with volume on the RPi3.  Have you tried setting the stream volume directly through AudioManager in the link you provided?

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the output volume on Android Things is somehow set to roughly half. I've tested with three different RPi 3 Bs, using the analog line out, two separate USB sound cards and the Adafruit MAX 98357A amplifier (using I2S bus output), and all produce sound at an incorrect level. I'm comparing this against booting those same devices into Raspbian or attaching the USB or amp to a different machine. My conclusion is that there must be a low-level issue in Android Things itself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes issue is solved trough setting volume with AudioManager.
Thanks a lot

UPDATE:
The code

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),0);
```

Comment: Hi @webaloman we have run into the same issue. Would you mind sharing the AudioManager code that solved it for you? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Smalesy see response